# How to iterate elements under ng-if div tag?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The parent div tag has ng-if condition. The child elements are ng-repeat. How should i iterate the elements under the parent div tag?

[image]

[image]

> Note: I need to iterate between the multiple ng-repeat elements inside the ng-if div tag. >

Comment: It's not linked to any array to iterate to

Comment: Could you add the actual part of html and js as a code block instead of an image

Comment: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater

Comment: @Gunderson I need to iterate between the multiple ng-repeat elements inside the ng-if div tag. Not in each ng-repeat!!

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over things in protractor you should use the [each()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) function.

```
element(by.css("[ng-if='formFields.length']")).all(by.repeater("formField in formFields")).each((el) => {
    // do something with each element
})
```

Your question is not clear - but if you are asking how to limit the locators to what's under the `ng-if` tag then you simply need a specific locator to that parent element.  I updated the above code.

Comment: I need to iterate between the multiple ng-repeat elements inside the ng-if div tag. Not in each ng-repeat!!

Comment: @JagdeepBhatta What do you mean?  Your question is not clear.  You asked "How to iterate elements under ng-if div tag?" and then put a red box around the `ng-repeat` elements.  So I told you how to iterate over those.  See my edit

Comment: I tried your approach but still its performing actions on only one ng-repeat. I want to select edit button of each ng-repeat and enter some text in the label field.